# How enable button on check the radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a foreach that contain 3 radio buttons, how do I enable a specific button when the radio button is checked? I have this:

```js
// Starts by disabling all the buttons
$('.btn-portabilizar').attr('disabled', true);

// If it is checked, enable the a specific button
$('input[name="autorizacao"]:checked').click(function(){
   $('.btn-portabilizar').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

And my view is this:

```
<% @autorizacoes.each do |autorizacao| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= radio_button_tag 'autorizacao', autorizacao.numero_contrato %></td>
        <td><%= autorizacao.numero_contrato %></td>
        <input class="string required" type="text" name="portabilidade_nova_parcela" id="portabilidade_nova_parcela">
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "Portabilizar", "#", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-portabilizar' %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Sorry for code in portuguese...

**UPDATE ==========================================**

When checked enable button, when unchecked disable button, I do it, but don't work:

```
  $('input[name="autorizacao"]').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn-portabilizar').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn-portabilizar').prop('disabled', true);

  });
```

What is my wrong?

Comment: just set disabled to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radio button selector is incorrect - you only attach it to radio buttons which are already checked on load, of which I'm assuming there are none. Remove the `:checked` part:

```
$('input[name="autorizacao"]').click(function(){
    $('.btn-portabilizar').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Also note that it's better practice to use `prop()` where possible.

To only affect the button in the same row you would need to use jQuery's DOM traversal methods, like this:

```
$('input[name="autorizacao"]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn-portabilizar').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: what is difference? I always use attr and removeAttr instead of prop

Comment: `prop()` sets the property of the DOMElement without having to a access the DOM directly. In other words it performs better.

Comment: @EltonSantos see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/519413) for a complete answer on the subject

Comment: hmmm thanks man!! But I have other problem, how enable just the button specific?? When I do what you say I enable all buttons... I need enable just the checked...

Comment: Do you can help one more time? I updated my question